# can I add optional types parameters in C++

Tags: c++, parameters

the title says it all.

I have this function that couts the parameter:

```
void outlog(string par) {

   std::cout << par;

}
```

but Par can only be a string. how can I make its type optional.

Comment: Are you asking about parameter type dependent function overloads? Yes that's possible. What specifically doesn't work with yours? You could also use a template: `template<typename T> void outlog(T par) { ...`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

C++ (and many other languages) makes it available to have generic functions. Here you can read more about it: [Generics in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generics-in-c/) Here is the sample code for your function. Note: the object should be printable (if it is a class object, it should have the `<<` operator overloaded):

```
template <typename T>
void outlog(T& input){
    std::cout << input;
}
```

Comment: `T&` won't make you happy in many situations.

Comment: That's another topic, he can pass it also as a const reference.

Comment: @manchi_o6o7 That definitely should be passed by value, or `const` reference!

Comment: Would this be a good place for auto&&?